# How to configure rules for wcag2aa in axe-core for selenium java

Tags: selenium

I want to add rules in axe in selenium for wcag2aa.
Can anyone help me with the syntax?

```
JSONObject responseJSON = new AXE.Builder(getBrowser()
                    .getWebDriver(), scriptUrl).options(
                    ("{ rules: { 'wcag2aa' } }")).analyze();
```

I have tried the above code but it is giving me exception

Thanks.

Comment: @curveball When making edits, you should remove salutations/thanks, as they are perceived by noise by most users.

Answer (score 0):

wcag2aa is a list of rules and not a rule itself.

Try:

.options("{ runOnly: ['wcag2aa'] }")

Or you can only run multiple lists of rules like so:

.options("{ runOnly: ['wcag2a', 'wcag2aa', 'best-practice'] }")

In this case the only list of rules that would not run is the 'section508' list.

[Check out the Axe API docs on the options parameter](https://www.deque.com/axe/axe-for-web/documentation/api-documentation/#options-parameter)